# How to check that one array of map contains map from another array of map?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I need to check that one array of Map contains another

```
def map1 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"], [key3:"value3", key4:"value4"]]
def map2 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"]]
```

Currently i have method which find map in array of map and compare them

`def "method"(map2){
    def map1 = arrayOfmap 
    def matches = map1.findAll { map2.contains(it) } 
    assert matches == map2 //return true
}`

Now I want to write a method that will search in the array of maps myMap and check that all the values from myMap are find in map1

For example:

I have

`def map1 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"], [key3:"value3", key4:"value4"]]
 def map2 = [[key1:"value1"]]`

I need check that map1 contains map2

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit: Would map2 be considered a match? Does the complete map need to be there? Does it just have to be any of the keys? Do the values have to match? Please add some more examples of matches and non-matches to your question.

Comment: Map1 should contains all values from map2

Comment: `def matches = map1.findAll {
    map2.contains(it)
   }
 assert matches == map2` I need something like this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but given:

```
def map1 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"], [key3:"value3", key4:"value4"]]
```

Assuming you mean that every element in `map2` has to occur in one of the maps in `map1`, you could do something like:

```
boolean allFoundIn(List<Map> map, List<Map> query) {
    query.every { m2 -> map.any { m1 -> m2.every { m2a -> m1[m2a.key] == m2a.value } } }
}

assert allFoundIn(map1, [[key1:'value1']])
assert allFoundIn(map1, [[key3:'value3'], [key2:'value2']])
assert !allFoundIn(map1, [[key1:'value1'], [keyNone:'not found']])

// Multiple values in one map have to all match the same map in the source
assert allFoundIn(map1, [[key1:'value1', key2:'value2']])
assert !allFoundIn(map1, [[key1:'value1', key3:'value3']])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not exactly what I need

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what you need? Can you edit the question, and put a few simple examples of positive and negative matches?

Comment: `def map1 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"], [key3:"value3", key4:"value4"]]` 
value in key2 - is generate by system (digital value)
I do not need to check it, so I just want to check that map1 contains def map2 = [[key1:"value1"]]

Comment: So you just need to check the "first" element of each of the maps in `map1`?  You know some maps have no order, yeah?

Comment: no, for first I need to make sure that map1 contains map2 and then we need compare this elements i mean maps

Comment: currently i have method which find map in array of map and compare them

Comment: `def "method"(map2){
   def map1 = arrayOfmap
   def matches = map1.findAll {
    map2.contains(it)
   }
   assert matches == map2
   return true
 }
`

Comment: I'm confused...can you edit your question and add what you have, and why this isn't good enough? Sorry, it's probably me being a bit slow this morning... And comments on StackOverflow aren't a good place for code (as you can see)

Comment: Also, I assume from this that the example in your question should return `false`?

Answer (score 0):

To find that `map1` (bit misleading example as `map1` is actually a list not a map) contains all the elements from `map2` (another list) you can either use the `containsAll` method, `intersect` method or subtract all the elements of `map1` from `map2`, note that on partial matching it does not pass, see `map3` below

```
def map1 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"], [key3:"value3", key4:"value4"]]
def map2 = [[key1:"value1", key2:"value2"]]
def map3 = [[key1:"value1"]]

assert map1.containsAll(map2)
assert map1.intersect(map2) == map2
assert map2 - map1 == []

assert !map1.containsAll(map3)
assert !map1.intersect(map3)
assert map3 - map1 != []
```